# How to launch IntelliJ on ubuntu from terminal

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, terminal

I have installed IntelliJ using the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mmk2410/intellij-idea-communitycode 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install intellij-idea-community
```

The problem is that whenever I try to launch it with ./file name I get the message that my permission is denied. How should I proceed in such situation?

Answer (score 2):

In the bin directory, just run ./idea.sh
(you might need to make it executable by chmod +x )

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 16.04 includes `snapd` by default.

To install IntelliJ IDEA Community:
 `$ sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic --edge`

And to run just type
 `$ intellij-idea-community`

Answer (score 0):

- Locate the installation Path of IntelliJ.use `which intellij-idea-ultimate` to find them manually.
- Go inside the folder and locate idea.sh and copy the folder path.
- Open terminal configuration file (if you're using zsh, open `~/zshrc` config file) using  `sudo nano ~/zshrc`
- Add `export PATH="/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/current/bin:$PATH" on config file
- Add alias `idea='/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/current/bin/idea.sh'`.
- Reload the config file using `source ~/.zshr`
- Type `idea ./ &`.IT will open IntelliJ from terminal
  See here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html#smart-command-execution for more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).